# jquery font resizer script not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple font resizer on a clients website that I'm using. I honestly cannot remember where I got the code snippet from, but it is acting a bit weird.

The functionality of the '+' and '-' works great, I have it set to decrease the font size by 4px or increase the font size by 1px, with decreasing as low as 16px and increasing as much as 28px.

However, on the first initial 'click' of the increase button, it shoots the font size all the way up to 1px lower than what the max increased size is supposed to be.

Why would it be doing this? Is there something more that I need to have added to the code? Is it something that has to deal with how the font sizes are setup for the elements that are being targeted?

code below

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $("#incfont").click(function() {
    curSize =
      parseInt(
      $(
        ".et_pb_text_inner *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3):not(h4):not(h5):not(h6)"
      ).css("font-size")
    ) + 1;
    if (curSize <= 28)
      $(
        ".et_pb_text_inner *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3):not(h4):not(h5):not(h6)"
      ).css("font-size", curSize);
    return false;
  });

  $("#decfont").click(function() {
    curSize =
      parseInt(
      $(
        ".et_pb_text_inner *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3):not(h4):not(h5):not(h6)"
      ).css("font-size")
    ) - 4;
    if (curSize >= 16)
      $(
        ".et_pb_text_inner *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3):not(h4):not(h5):not(h6)"
      ).css("font-size", curSize);
    return false;
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="text-resizer">
  <div class="aa">A<span>A</span></div>
  <p>Text Size</p>
  <a href="#" id="incfont">+</a>
  <a href="#" id="decfont">-</a>
</div>
```

I would like for it to just increase intially by the 1px that is set in the jQuery, I don't know why it does it the way it is now.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the link, but you can also view it live at http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/about-us/

Comment: in this [bin](https://jsbin.com/mofilunuxo/edit?html,js,output) all working as mentioned. Probably this behaivor is causes some other part of the code.

Comment: Why don't you try to console.log the values that are getting changed? I can assure you that if you console.log curSize you'll start to see what's going on under the hood and what's causing your error.

Comment: @yoursweater, i tried using the console.log and all it shows me is the value of the size the text is being set to, which is 27, considering the max is 28.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. It looks like your font-size is being overwritten on line 66 of your CSS. It's setting font-size to 100%. I'm pretty sure that's what is causing your error - the #incfont click function is looking at cursize and it's not 22px.. it's whatever weird value being set by font-size: 100%. Now, once you've clicked on #incfont, the font-size is explicitly set at 27px and everything works as intended. So, I think the suggested fix would be to add a line of CSs at the bottom of your stylesheet saying .et_pb_text_inner {font-size:22px;}

Comment: The body font size is setup that way for whatever reason by the Theme creator, Divi (elegantthemes), however the 14px is the one that takes precedence over the 100%. Also, not all sections of the page are set at the 22px. most are at 16, but some are at 18, 20, 22, it just depends on the page -- so setting that line of CSS in my stylesheet would be useless